# List.pop() in Django Template without for loop

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery, django-templates

I have a list of id all_entries_user. They basically serve as a part of url for rest service that I have developed using TastyPie. Inside my Django template i want to use them by iterating all_entries_user

```
function ajaxCall(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/Location/" + {{ all_entries_user.pop }} + "/?format=json",
    function(json) {
    convert(json,"googleMapUser");
        }
    );
}
```

Using this I am getting values from Service and this happens in a continous interval .

```
 interval = startInterval(ajaxCall, 3000);
```

The value of url must change for each call and it must be taken from list

```
  all_entries_user
```

gives me the same id every time.

I tried to pop values but each time gives me same value

I havent found an efficient way to iterate through this.

Suggestions and Help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the [`for` construct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)?

```
{% for user in all_entries_user %}
    Do your thing with {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: its like this ajax call is to happen 10 times but I want the value of change for all calls and it must be taken from the list

Comment: This is the only viable option though I had to tweak my requirements a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's very confusing when you mix two languages. What's happening is your javascript is getting "Built" once when the template is rendered so you only have one URL regardless of how many times javascript hits that method. You can verify this by using view source and checking out what your javascript looks like to the client.

If you want the client to call a different URL each time, you will have to send all the IDs down to the client first. One way to do this is by using json serializer or just a simple home grown javascript array builder.

Something like this might work:

```
<script>
   var allEntries = [{% for entry in all_entries_user %}{{ entry.id }},{% endfor %}];
   for (entryId in allEntries) {
      doSomethingWith(entryId);
   }
</script>
```

This isn't the best way to populate an array of javascript from django, but it works in a hurry.